# Prevent double clicking on column section from triggering doubletapped event

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

So I have a ListView with a DoubleTapped event attached to it in .XAML. The problem is that I don't want it to register when I'm double clicking on a column section. Only when double clicking on any other section of the control. Can I somehow specify it in the .XAML, or maybe detect it in the code in the event handler that the click was on the columns and therefore do no action?

I tried checking DataContext type of source in EventArgs, but it's the same whether you click on columns or on some other space.

I expected to be able to detect that the click occurred on the columns section and therefore take no action in the event handler.

I didn't manage to detect that the click occurred on the columns section why

Comment: What do you mean by columns section?

Comment: `RoutedEventArgs` has `Source` and `OriginalSource` properties. Starting from these you can analyse the visual tree the event is triggered from.

Comment: @lidqy I already tried these but it gives the same objects whether I click on the columns section or on some other things. And by the columns section I mean the grid header

Comment: @Andy it's the column header where the names for columns displayed and you can sort by clicking on them, etc

Comment: Nevermind, I just added the DoubleTapped event to the ListView.Header and set e.handled to true in the event handler method. The problem is fixed now.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot to mark the area where you want to implement the double-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix a problem, I just needed to add the same DoubleTapped event to the ListView.Header element and then in the event handler method set e.handled to true. That thing fixed the issue.